# Trigger onchange action jquery

Tags: jquery, html, events, select, listener

I have a select box with an onchange property
I can change the value of the box but can't trigger the onchange aoutmatically

```
<select name="name" id="id7c7" onchange="if (function()...."> 

$(document).ready(function() {

var id1 = $( "select:first-of-type" ).attr('id')
var event = new Event('onchange', { 'bubbles': true });


console.dir();

// sets first drop to category
$( "select:first-of-type" ).val( "2" );
$( "select:first-of-type" ).dispatchEvent(event)'



});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete this: `$( "select:first-of-type" ).dispatchEvent(event)'`

Insert this instead: `$("#id7c7").trigger( "change" );`

This triggers the change event on your select input. I tried with an alert as onchange function, worked as expected.

Comment: tried that it didn't work also the element name is variable based on the page load how would I call the var

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {

    var id1 = $( "select:first-of-type" ).attr('id')
    var id2 = "#" + $( "select:first-of-type" ).attr('id')
 

    console.dir();

    // sets first drop to category
    $( "select:first-of-type" ).val( "2" );
    $(id2).trigger( "change" );


    });

Comment: The code I posted does exactly what you wanted: Triggering the change event when your script changes the selected option. See https://codepen.io/happy_ant/pen/EzvPpL . If it's not working for you, then there must be something wrong with the rest of your code. You never told anybody that your code is dynamic, so your initial question is answered. As far as I know it's not allowed to extend a posted question, so you'll have to open a new one.